# Blender - Export .obj with normalized UV Coordinates

Tags: opengl, blender, uv-mapping

I want export .obj files from Blender. I export them with normals and UV Coordinates. I then import them into an OpenGl application. In UV Editor I am able to display the coordinates of the cursor normalized. My Problem is that I need to export them normalized because OpenGL needs them that way. Is there any possibility to do this or do I have to write and application which converts them manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the texture coordinates should be exported in normalized coordinates already. Do you have an excerpt of one of the exported OBJ files with the texture coordinates you think that are off?

Comment: i have marked about 1/8 of the texture in the UV editor and get this:  vt 0.013100 0.886290
vt 0.113710 0.886290
vt 0.113710 0.986900
vt 0.013100 0.986900

Comment: @Geosearchef: So? Those values look about right. You just probably have used the upper left 1/8th of the texture, but since the origin is in the lower left that means that values for the T coordinate will be somewhere between 1-1/8 = 0.875 to 1 which are exactly the values you have there. The S values look right as well, the left 1/8 go from 0 to 0.124, which again is the value range you have there.

Comment: Omg! You're right! My fail, sry. I'm used to my coordinate system in OpenGL which i have setup to have (0|0) int the upper left, i will just convert the coords. Thx!